# FindAndModify, return array of Objects

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to modify multiple documents with `findAndModify`, and then return the new Documents modified.
My query is:

```
db.users.findAndModify({
  query: {
    _id: {
      $in: [
        ObjectId("54061f3c27afac4b44688c1d"),
        ObjectId("54061f3c27afac4b44688c1e")
      ]
    }
  },
  update: {
    $inc: {
      i: 1
    }
  },
  new: true
});
```

but can retrieve only one document. My aim is to modify multi documents, and return all of them. Is it possible to retrieve an array of documents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) in the documents, `findAndModify` "modifies and returns a single document". If you want to modify multiple documents using `findAndModify` you will have to run it once per document. In the `mongo` shell, you can achieve that with some JavaScript like the following:

```js
var oids = [ObjectId("54061f3c27afac4b44688c1d"),
            ObjectId("54061f3c27afac4b44688c1e")];
docs = [];
for (var i in oids) {
    id = oids[i];
    doc = db.e.findAndModify({
        "query": { "_id": id },
        "update": { "$inc": { "i": 1 }},
        "new": true
    });
    docs.push(doc);
}
printjson(docs);
```

The other option would be to run `update` using `multi` as an option and then retrieve the documents. Your code would look something like the following:

```js
db.users.update(
    { "_id": {
        "$in": [ObjectId("54061f3c27afac4b44688c1d"),
                ObjectId("54061f3c27afac4b44688c1e")]
        }
    },
    { "$inc": { "i": 1 }},
    { "multi": true }
);
db.users.find(
    { "_id": {
        "$in": [ObjectId("54061f3c27afac4b44688c1d"),
                ObjectId("54061f3c27afac4b44688c1e")]
        }
    }
);
```